# Equivalent criteria for below sql query?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I am using Hibernate. I have the following SQL query. I have to convert it to criteria. How can I achieve it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT username 
    FROM usertable 
    WHERE user_id in (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM someother_table);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for if you've mapped "user_id" as property and didn't map any relationships (if you did the right property might be "myEntity.user.id" instead of "myEntity.user_id")

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(MyEntity.class, "myEntity");

//setting projection to distinct(myEntity.username)
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("myEntity.username")));

DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MyOtherEntity.class, "myOtherEntity");
subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("myOtherEntity.user_id")));

criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("myEntity.user_id", subCriteria));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. above query did not return any results. i made a small change. i replaced propertyIn with exists then it worked. my question is above query returns individual usernames. but i want all MyEntity objects. Please help me.

Comment: Hi,

well exists wouldn't make much sense in that context. It would just ask if the subquery returns anything. How did you map myEntity.user_id ?
To return a distinct set of MyEntity objects you would have to use
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
instead of
criteria.setProjection(...)